# How to get those names which have 2 or more rows linked with them in an other table by the ID of their row

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

I've used this code to create the database and two tables:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS shop;
CREATE DATABASE shop CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
USE shop;

CREATE TABLE manufacturer (
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE product (
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  price DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  manufacturer_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_id) REFERENCES manufacturer(id)
);

INSERT INTO manufacturer VALUES(1, 'Asus');
INSERT INTO manufacturer VALUES(2, 'Lenovo');
INSERT INTO manufacturer VALUES(3, 'Hewlett-Packard');
INSERT INTO manufacturer VALUES(4, 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO manufacturer VALUES(5, 'Seagate');
INSERT INTO manufacturer VALUES(6, 'Crucial');
INSERT INTO manufacturer VALUES(7, 'Gigabyte');
INSERT INTO manufacturer VALUES(8, 'Huawei');
INSERT INTO manufacturer VALUES(9, 'Xiaomi');

INSERT INTO product VALUES(1, 'Disco duro SATA3 1TB', 86.99, 5);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(2, 'Memoria RAM DDR4 8GB', 120, 6);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(3, 'Disco SSD 1 TB', 150.99, 4);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(4, 'GeForce GTX 1050Ti', 185, 7);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(5, 'GeForce GTX 1080 Xtreme', 755, 6);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(6, 'Monitor 24 LED Full HD', 202, 1);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(7, 'Monitor 27 LED Full HD', 245.99, 1);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(8, 'Portátil Yoga 520', 559, 2);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(9, 'Portátil Ideapd 320', 444, 2);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(10, 'Impresora HP Deskjet 3720', 59.99, 3);
INSERT INTO product VALUES(11, 'Impresora HP Laserjet Pro M26nw', 180, 3);
```

Expected result:
**Returns a list with the names of manufacturers that have 2 or more products.**

I've tried these queries but both return an empty set:

```
SELECT manufacturer.name FROM product INNER JOIN manufacturer ON product.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.id WHERE (SELECT COUNT(product.id)) >= 2 GROUP BY manufacturer.name;
```

```
SELECT manufacturer.name FROM product INNER JOIN manufacturer ON product.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.id WHERE (SELECT COUNT(producto.id) FROM producto) >= 2 GROUP BY manufacturer.name;
```

Comment: there's a type error. The second query I've tried is as follows:

**SELECT manufacturer.name FROM product INNER JOIN manufacturer ON product.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.id WHERE (SELECT COUNT(product.id) FROM product) >= 2 GROUP BY manufacturer.name;**

Comment: What else did you try to resolve the problem? Are you using MySQL or MariaDB?

Comment: I'm using MySQL. I haven't tried any more, the answer of @SelVazi worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to do it :

First get all the manufacturers that have 2 or more products from product table using `group by` and `having count(1) >= 2` :

```
select manufacturer_id
from product
group by manufacturer_id
having count(1) >= 2
```

Then join this dataset with the manufacturer table :

```
select m.name
from manufacturer m
inner join (
  select manufacturer_id
  from product
  group by manufacturer_id
  having count(1) >= 2
) as s on s.manufacturer_id = m.id
```

Result :

```
name
Asus
Lenovo
Hewlett-Packard
Crucial
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/XRUfYtLW)